# How to properly close file-to-string input stream? (IOUtils FileUtils)

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, assets, fileutils

I have two file-to-string processes in my app (one actually deals with an asset file).
If I repeat either of these processes a few times on the same file, I get OutOfMemoryErrors.
I suspect it might be because I'm not closing the streams properly and therefore maybe causing multiple streams to be created, and this is perhaps causing my app to run out of memory.
Here is the code of the two processes:

My asset-file-to-string process.
As you can see, I have have something in place to close the stream but I don't know if it's formatted properly.

```
try 
{
      myVeryLargeString = IOUtils.toString(getAssets().open(myAssetsFilePath), "UTF-8");
      IOUtils.closeQuietly(getAssets().open(myAssetsFilePath));
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
      e.printStackTrace();
}
catch(OutOfMemoryError e)
{
      Log.e(TAG, "Ran out of memory 01");
}
```

My file-to-string process.
I have no idea how to close this stream (if there is even a stream to close at all).

```
myFile01 = new File(myFilePath);
try 
{
      myVeryLargeString = FileUtils.readFileToString(myFile01, "UTF-8");
} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
      e.printStackTrace();
}
catch(OutOfMemoryError e)
{
      Log.e(TAG, "Ran out of memory 02");
}
```

Comment: IOUtils and fileutils is your class??

Comment: my guess is you are opening the stream twice then closing it `getAssets().open(myAssetsFilePath)` looks suspect

Comment: Consider placing `close()` calls in a `finally` block.

Comment: @Ashish Aggarwal: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @BevynQ Both of the processes are causing the OutOfMemoryErrors though; not just the assets one. Also, if you think that bit of code is suspect, do you perhaps know what I should change it to? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to say what may cause OOME but closing should be like this

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open(myAssetsFilePath);
try {
    myVeryLargeString = IOUtils.toString(is, "UTF-8");
} finally {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you happen to also have a suggestion for closing the second process that I posted? (the FileUtils process) Is there even a stream that needs to be closed in that one?

Comment: No, FileUtils.readFileToString closes the InputStream internally

Comment: Eclipse isn't allowing me to use this format. It wants the getAssets() part to be inside of the try/catch.

Comment: You can use try - catch - finally. Or simply declare that the method which contains the code throws IOException

Comment: Do you mean I should create an additional try/catch around the line that contains getAssets()? If so, should both of the try/catch have a finally + closeQuietly, or just the first try/catch?

Comment: just try {...} catch(IOException e) {...} finally {...}

Comment: That's how I currently have it arranged but Eclipse wants the line that contains "getAssets()" to be inside of a try/catch ... and, if I do put it inside of a try/catch, the "is" becomes no longer valid in the "final" section ("is" becomes red-underlined)

Comment: I see, right, open() may throw IOExeption, you need another try - catch around try - finally

Comment: That worked .. no more red underlining. Unfortunately, the OOME still exists (the process runs fine at first but I get the OOME usually on the second or third time of running the process). But, my question was about closing the input stream and you answered that. After you edit your answer to include the additional try/catch I'll choose it. Thanks again for the help. I appreciate it.

Comment: I discovered something using Eclipse Memory Analyzer. The reason I'm getting the OOME during the 2nd & 3rd run of the process (and not during the first run) is a single variable that was loading up with 3MB of text during the first run without getting emptied at the end of the first run (why it has 3MB of text when the file that's being read only contains 1.5 MB of text, I don't know). Apparently, the process of reading a 1.5MB file into a string variable uses up almost all of the memory available to the app, so not having that extra 3MB available was enough to cause the OOME.